# why does python skip user input sometimes?

Tags: python, input

i'm no expert, but code should be run as written?
i've noticed that latley in a few of my scripts, python will just skip user input, and instead save the variable as '' or nohting. whats up with this?
here is an example:

```
spc_01=input(f'enter file id of first asset to associate\n')
spc_02=input(f'enter file id of second asset to associate\n')
```

output:

```
enter file id of first asset to associate
obj:f0001:g0001:s0001-0001-fbx1-0000

enter file id of second asset to associate
^^^Running ALM_Find_Dir
```

it just skips past allowing user input! (a few lines down is where I run another script, not really relivant its just there to show how the user input part was skipped)
the script it is running is called "ALM_Find_Dir" and I put that print() fuction in there.
i've other examples ofthis,
so, why does python skip input sometimes?

Comment: It looks like you pressed enter twice, or pasted some text containing two newlines. `input()` reads until the first newline it encounters, which may just be the empty string, e.g. if you just press enter without typing anything.

Comment: Also, since you are not using string interpolation no need for the `f` before each string (causes reader confusion).

Comment: Are those "^^^" part of the print you added for ALM_Find_Dir?

Comment: yes, I added those carrots ^^^, its part of a long program, and just helps know whatsup. I learned python by doing this, so therese some context

Comment: could you expand on what string interpolation is, or post a link. so after using fstring the frist time, the rest of the lines don't need it, kinda like importing a module?

Comment: @ alex, i've run this a few times, and similar issues with input in other scripts

Comment: @MarlonD.Alessandra - You used and f-string (`f"whatever"`) without actually having any data expand in the string. That is a bit less performant than leaving the "f" off of the front. Only add the "f" if you are planning on inserting data in the string.

Comment: You could `print(f"spc_01: {spc_01!r}, spc_02: {spc_02!r}")` right after the input to see what you get. And that _should_ be an f-string because we expand the variables in it.

Comment: Your code is behaving as though there is an extra newline coming in after that first line of input text. It may be related to how you run the program. Which operating system? Running on the command line? Do you try to enter that second line of text?

Comment: it needs fstring for the new line charactor... thanks for the help here, cuz i'm stuck. the system is windows 11, i run using idle shell, becasue I cant figure out visual studio.  I need to save two inputs as two variables.

Comment: runs fine vai command prompt.

Comment: fstring is not needed for the new line character.  fstring is for string interpolation but you don't have any variables to interpolate in the strings.